# Vuetify Form Validation using Regex Expression

Tags: regex, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to get my vuetify form to validate my text box on the following criteria "AB-12345678" or if user forgos the hyphen and just puts in a number with a max of 8 digits. Can regex rules account for both of these scenarios in a single expression? My code so far:

```
        <v-form ref="sidebarSearchForm" lazy-validation v-on:submit.prevent>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <v-text-field label="Search"
                      single-line
                      filled
                      rounded
                      dense
                      append-icon="mdi-magnify"
                      v-model="id"
                      :rules"[v => !!v || 'ID Required!']"
                      @@click:append="searchID"
                      v-bind="{error: !validationProp,...(!validationProp && { 'error-messages': ['ID not found!'] })}"></v-text-field>
    </v-form>
```

Comment: regex to match both AB-12345678 and 12345678, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the full example:
using this regex

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{0,8}$|^\d{0,8}$)
```

- AA1221212 (**Not valid**)
- AA-111 (**Valid**)
- AA-12345678 (**Valid**))
- ABC-12345678 (**Not valid**)
- 12345678 (**Valid**)
- 123456789 (**Not valid**)
- 123 (**Valid**)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    valid: true,
    id: '',
    idRules: [
      v => !!v || 'Field is required',
      v => /^([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{0,8}$|^\d{0,8}$)/.test(v) || 'Expression must be valid'
    ],
   
  }),

  methods: {
    validate () {
      this.$refs.form.validate()
    },
    reset () {
      this.$refs.form.reset()
    },
    resetValidation () {
      this.$refs.form.resetValidation()
    },
  },
})
```

```html
   
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <v-container>
      
<v-form
      ref="form"
      v-model="valid"
      lazy-validation
    >
      <v-text-field
        v-model="id"
        :counter="10"
        :rules="idRules"
        label="Search"
        required
      ></v-text-field>
  
     
      <v-btn
        :disabled="!valid"
        color="success"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="validate"
      >
        Validate
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="error"
        class="mr-4"
        @click="reset"
      >
        Reset Form
      </v-btn>
  
      <v-btn
        color="warning"
        @click="resetValidation"
      >
        Reset Validation
      </v-btn>
    </v-form>
      
      </v-container>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was trying to go for AA-12345678 (full format with two character ID with hyphen then max 8 digit number) or 12345678  or 123 or 123 (any number but max 8 digits). Your regex makes sense but it doesnt account for just numbers by themselves max 8 digits.

Comment: Check now I update the regex

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple rules using regex or simple like this:

*(Update the **regex** as per your requirement)*

```
 <v-text-field
      v-model="id"
      :rules="idRules"
      label="Search"
      required
    ></v-text-field>


data: () => ({
        idRules: [
        v => !!v || 'Field is required',
        v => /.+@.+\..+/.test(v) || 'Expression must be valid',
      ],
  }),
```

Comment: Can you add the regex expression for this use case above and I will accept this answer. I was struggling with that aspect actually .

Comment: Yes I added full code for you (For a better view you can see it on the full page )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match both (2 letters)-(8 digits) and (8 digits)

Try this:

```
^([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{8})$|^(\d{8})$
```

In vue rules:

```
v => /^([a-zA-Z]{2}-\d{8})$|^(\d{8})$/.test(v) || 'Expression must be valid',
```

https://regex101.com/r/37EqR9/1

Comment: THe first part is correct but the second option should be any number less than 999999999  in any form just a digit though. So 1234 or 00001234. That website is pretty neat though.